# Cypress Fixture - TypeError: Cannot read property 'travelData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

Getting error in `Cypress test execution with fixture - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'travelData' of undefined"`

Here are the steps:

1 - Created a `travelData.json` file and put it into the fixtures folder:

```
{
  "FIRSTNAME": "TESTTRAVEL",
  "LASTNAME": "USER",
  "MOBILE": "581234567",
  "EMAIL": "test@test.com",
  "PASSPORT": "AB1234",
  "CURRENCY": "AED"
}
```

2 - Write a Cypress test and put into the `integration` folder. Code is below:

```
context('Travel Portal Regression Test', () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.fixture('travel.testData').then((travelData) => {
      this.travelData = travelData;
    });
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    // cy.viewport('iphone-6')
    cy.viewport(360, 640);
    cy.visit('https://thoughtcoders.com/');
  });

  it('Testing ThoughtCoders Homepage', () => {
    cy.log('Testing ThoughtCoders Homepage');
    cy.log(this.travelData.FIRSTNAME);
  });
});
```

When I run the Cypress test then I get the error **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'travelData' of undefined"**.

Please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

You can use the [`wrap()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html) method which yields the `object` passed as a `param` if it resolves like so:

```
context('Travel Portal Regression Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture('travelData').then((data) => cy.wrap(data).as('getTravelData'));
    // cy.viewport('iphone-6')
    cy.viewport(360, 640);
    cy.visit('https://thoughtcoders.com/');
  });

  it('Testing ThoughtCoders Homepage', () => {
    cy.log('Testing ThoughtCoders Homepage');
    cy.get('@getTravelData').then((res) => cy.log(res.FIRSTNAME));
  });
});
```

**Solution 2:**

You can declare a variable called `travelData` on the upper scope of your test spec & reassign its value to `data` received from the `json` file like so:

```
context('Travel Portal Regression Test', () => {
  let travelData;

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture('travelData').then((data) => {
      travelData = data;
      return travelData;
    });
    // cy.viewport('iphone-6')
    cy.viewport(360, 640);
    cy.visit('https://thoughtcoders.com/');
  });

  it('Testing ThoughtCoders Homepage', () => {
    cy.log('Testing ThoughtCoders Homepage');
    cy.log(travelData.FIRSTNAME);
  });
});
```

Here it's the screenshot with the test results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Fixture Example Recipe](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/db2f5a9c2e3dcf3b4f2b352f10a2d6ed443946fe/examples/fundamentals__fixtures/cypress/integration/load-fixtures-spec.js#L103) which shows a simple way to load the fixture ***once only*** and persist it for each test in the spec

The pattern is to add an additional `beforeEach()` in between your `before()` and current `beforeEach()`.

**Example recipe**

```js
context('loading once and using @', () => {
  let city
  let country

  before(() => {
    // load fixtures just once, need to store in
    // closure variables because Mocha context is cleared
    // before each test
    cy.fixture('city').then((c) => {
      city = c
    })

    cy.fixture('country').then((c) => {
      country = c
    })
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    // we can put data back into the empty Mocha context before each test
    // by the time this callback executes, "before" hook has finished
    cy.wrap(city).as('city')
    cy.wrap(country).as('country')
  })

  it('has loaded fixtures', function () {
    // again, the test has to use "function" callback
    // to make sure "this" points at the Mocha context
    expect(this.city).to.deep.equal({ name: 'Atlanta' })
    expect(this.country).to.deep.equal({ name: 'United States' })
  })
})
```

Three key points you need are

1. use a closure variable
2. use a beforeEach() to "put back" the variable after clearing
3. use a "function () {}" style test

**In your test**

```js
context('loading once and persisting the fixture', () => {

  let travelData                                                 // key point #1

  before(() => {
    cy.fixture('travelData').then((data) => {                  
      travelData = data;
    });
  })

  beforeEach(() => {                                             // key point #2
    cy.wrap(travelData).as('travelData')
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.viewport(360, 640);
    cy.visit('https://thoughtcoders.com/');
  });

  it('Testing ThoughtCoders Homepage', function () {             // key point #3 
    expect(this.travelData."FIRSTNAME").to.equal("TESTTRAVEL")   // passes
  })
})
```

Comment: Nice, this does not load the fixture on every test like the other example does.